# Unable to access Array inside JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

For the life of me, I can not figure out why this is not working.

I am opening a websocket connection using WS v8+

I receive a message and parse it to JSON.

```
ws.on('message', function message(data) {
  var message = data.toString()
  console.log(message)
});
```

Now the output is as expected:

```
{"method": "state.update", "params": [{"BTCUSDT": {"last": "27427.41"}}], "id": null}
```

I can read the message.method and message.params as expected. The problem is accessing the array inside "params":

```
ws.on('message', function message(data) {
  var message = data.toString()
  console.log(data.params[0]) // FAILS
});

ws.on('message', function message(data) {
  var message = data.toString()
  console.log(data.params)
  // OUTPUT: [{"BTCUSDT": {"last": "27427.41"}}]
});
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why it is failing to see the params as an array with any length for this very simple task.

UPDATE:

With the WS library, the need to use toString() from the Buffer was there. With WS 7 this was not needed.

Also the params field is not showing up as an array which explains why length and other indexes aren't working but very confused as why it isn't being read as an array with the output I am seeing.

```
ws.on('message', function message(data) {
    var message = data.toString()
    var output = JSON.parse(message)
    console.log( Array.isArray(output.params) )    // RETURNS FALSE   
 });
```

Comment: Code looks fine. What result do you get from `Array.isArray(data.params)`? Also, what does `FAILS` mean? It throws an error? It doesn't print anything?

Comment: Does `toString()` mutate the `data` object at all? Since you're not doing anything with `message` yet, I would recommend removing it to focus on the problem at hand. Also, try some more detailed logging... `console.log('on[message]:', typeof data, data, JSON.stringify(data))`

Comment: There are some inconsistencies with the question, notably, you seem to be missing `JSON.parse(data)` from your solution, which is a red flag with the `ws` library.  What's confusing is that you later say you can read from `data.params` which directly conflicts with this observation.   Is there code above that is missing or is this THE issue?

Comment: With WS 8+ the data came as a buffer so needed to run toString() to convert it. With WS 7 it wasn't needed so took it out.

For the other questions:

The odd part is the field in the console is an array but the Array.isArray() returns FALSE.

Here is the latest version with WS 8+ updated in the original question.

Comment: Thanks, however, this doesn't match my tests (neither the `toString()` requirement, nor the Array bug).  Can you update the example to include steps to reproduce?  For example, when I tested, I used a small `test.js` file and ran it with Node; I sent the data using a browser `WebSocket` object.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using [this `ws` library](https://github.com/websockets/ws), it appears you're assuming the data is in JSON format, but I can't find any documentation to support that assumption.

Try calling `JSON.parse(data)` before iterating your object.

```js
ws.on('message', function message(data) {
  var json = JSON.parse(data) // <----- HERE
  console.log(json.params[0])
});
```

Comment: Just like a previous and now deleted answer, this doesn't explain how OP sees an array for `console.log(data.params)`

Comment: @Phil can you please help show where "OP sees an array"?

Comment: It's right in the question... `console.log(data.params)` and `// OUTPUT: [{"BTCUSDT": {"last": "27427.41"}}]`. I'm not saying your answer is wrong and it's probably more likely that the code and output in the question itself is not accurate but that's all we've got to work with unless OP clarifies

Comment: I double-checked `ws`: `console.log(data.params)` returns `undefined` whereas `console.log(JSON.parse(data).params)` returns `[ { BTCUSDT: { last: '27427.41' } } ]`.   The OPs frustration is evident by the "For the life of me...", so it's within reason (and the only logical explanation) that the OP did once have valid results, but made a sane, human mistake in both their own code -- and inevitably -- in the accuracy of explaining it.

Comment: That's quite a number of assumptions you're making there.

Comment: ... whereas "code looks fine" is objectively right? ;)

Comment: To word this differently:  To prove the conspiracy that the OP did NOT make a typo would require the following conspiracies to be simultanously true: 1. A library referred to as `WS v8+` that uses the distinct `.on(...)` notation must exist -- AND --  2.  That library must receive message as a raw `JSON` object, not as String -- AND --.  3.  That raw `JSON` object must display the exact array anomaly. ....  Otherwise, occam's razor.

Comment: So, if you're convinced that it's a typo, vote to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". In any other scenario, unless you have an answer that answers the question as stated, it should be closed as "Needs details or clarity" or "Needs debugging details".

Comment: Sorry, but that's prescriptive toxicity.  The question is well written, but the troubleshooting contains either a false assumption or a typo.  In the event I'm wrong, I've asked the OP to clarify.  Voting to close is just cruel, as it discourages other good questions (and answers) from this OP.

Comment: I tested this parsing and it still doesn't read the params part of the object as an Array. Added some code above to the original question but now just confused how the [] field isn't being read as an array.

Comment: @boxxa thanks.  I've added some comments to the original question in an attempt to reproduce what you're seeing, notably working from a minimally reproducible code example (and steps thereof).